# ClassCastException: MediaMetadataRetriever cannot be cast to AutoCloseable

Tags: android, kotlin, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-6.0.1-marshmallow

I tried to use `MediaMetadataRetriever` with Kotlin `use`:

```
MediaMetadataRetriever().apply {
    setDataSource(context, uri)
}.use {
    ...
}
```

But it gives me an error on Android 6 Marshmallow (23 API):

> java.lang.ClassCastException: android.media.MediaMetadataRetriever
> cannot be cast to java.lang.AutoCloseable

Why so?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`MediaMetadataRetriever` implements `AutoCloseable` [since API level 29](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaMetadataRetriever#close()).

Comment: got it, now we should check `close` method in documentation for all other similar classes, I think `Kotlin use` func should some how check (or some internal Android Studio plugin, I believe it's possible) if class doesn't implements `AutoCloseable` and give a warning

Answer (score 0):

Android is open source project, you can check the sources for every revision. Seems it started to implement AutoClosable not long ago

API 28:

```
public class MediaMetadataRetriever
{
```

API 30

```
public class MediaMetadataRetriever implements AutoCloseable {
```

Comment: yeah, from 29 API

Answer (score 0):

When you say you are using "Kotlin" `use` method I assume you are referring to the one in `androidx.core.content.res` package at `androidx.core:core-ktx` library.

But this one does not use `AutoCloseable` interface at all. Instead `MediaMetadataRetriever` class also provides of a `use` method since API 29, as user sdex states in his answer, which you might be using by mistake.

On the contrary, `use` method from `androidx` is backwards compatible.

Then, you just have to import the following:

```
import androidx.core.content.res.use
```